# swift client delete object failed

Tags: openstack-swift

#### Environment

- swift client in CentOS7(10.0.0.2)
  `bash
  [root@bogon ~]# pip2 show python-swiftclient
  Name: python-swiftclient
  Version: 2.7.0
  Summary: OpenStack Object Storage API Client Library
  Home-page: http://www.openstack.org/
  Author: OpenStack
  Author-email: openstack-dev@lists.openstack.org
  License: UNKNOWN
  Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  Requires: futures, six, requests`
- swift server in CentOS7(10.0.0.4)
  `bash
  [root@bogon ~]# swift --version
  python-swiftclient 3.2.1.dev9`

#### Question

- swift client login server ，and delete one .jpg file in the container "temporary".

#### Details

`[root@bogon ~]# swift -A http://10.0.0.4:8080/auth/v1.0 -U admin:admin -K admin_pass list
contract
data
mask_contract
temporary

[root@bogon ~]# swift -A http://10.0.0.4:8080/auth/v1.0 -U admin:admin -K 806huayuan list temporary | tail
9f2f8626-a2ad-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
a25ebf08-a2b0-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
a6cfc990-a2ad-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
a8732914-a216-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
a87cda6a-77f8-11e7-befe-1866daecc1a0.jpg
ad186efc-a216-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
b255e2e6-a216-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
d1d010f2-0129-11e8-8cef-1866daecc1a0.jpg
f779a1ea-a2ad-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg
ff4fbf7e-aa70-11e7-bbe0-1866daecc1a0.jpg

[root@bogon ~]# swift -A http://10.0.0.4:8080/auth/v1.0 -U admin:admin -K 806huayuan delete temporary ff4fbf7e-aa70-11e7-bbe0-1866daecc1a0.jpg
Error Deleting: temporary/f779a1ea-a2ad-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg: Object DELETE failed: http://10.0.0.4:8080/v1/AUTH_admin/temporary/f779a1ea-a2ad-11e7-ad0b-1866daecc1a0.jpg 409 Conflict  [first 60 chars of response] There was a conflict when trying t`

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The reason is that the timestamp assigned to the delete is earlier than the timestamp of the objects.

http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-dev/2014-April/033438.html